# Dropbox drop-in saver local host file error

Tags: javascript, dropbox-api

Is possible localhost file upload to dropbox via drop-in saver?(https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/saver)

I'm tried this , but i got an error class (dropbox-dropin-error).

My code

```
<a class="dropbox-saver" href="http://localhost/app/backup.sql">SAVE TO DROPBOX</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible to upload a local hosted file to Dropbox via drop-in saver, drop-in saver just let you download a file to your Dropbox quota so it need an **public accessible URL** to download that file on Dropbox servers while **localhost URL is only accessible for you**.